# Recursive read images files in provided folder

Tags: node.js

I am getting folder absolute path and I want to extract all text files path from the folder (recursively).

This is what I've tried:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');


const getFolderImagesRecursive = async (folderPath) => {
    const directoryChildren = await fs.readdir(folderPath);

    return directoryChildren.reduce(async (finalArray, directoryChild) => {
        const fullPath = path.join(folderPath, directoryChild);
        const pathStat = await fs.lstat(fullPath);

        if (pathStat.isDirectory()) {
            const recursiveResult = await getFolderImagesRecursive(fullPath);

            return [
                ...finalArray,
                ...recursiveResult,
            ];
        } else if (fullPath.split('.').pop() === 'txt') {
            return [
                ...finalArray,
                fullPath,
            ]
        } else {
            return finalArray;
        }
    }, []);
}
```

For testing purpose I've created dummy folders and text files or folders nested inside. When tried the function on the main test folder I got:`TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) on line 21`.

Does anyone observe the error and can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that array.reduce is a synchronous function. And when you pass it an async function the result it gets is a promise. Not an array. The problem is that the *finalArray* (after the first iteration) **is a promise that returns an array**. And you're trying to destructure the promise on line 21. You should rewrite your code using loops instead of async/await like this

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');


const getFolderImagesRecursive = (folderPath) => {
  const directoryChildren = fs.readdirSync(folderPath);
  const finalArray = [];

  directoryChildren.forEach(directoryChild => {
    const fullPath = path.join(folderPath, directoryChild);
    const pathStat = fs.lstatSync(fullPath);

    if (pathStat.isDirectory()) {
      const recursiveResult = getFolderImagesRecursive(fullPath);
      finalArray.concat(recursiveResult);
    } else if (fullPath.split('.').pop() === 'txt') {
      finalArray.push(fullPath);
    }
  })

  return finalArray;
}
}
```